# Example of $f$, $g$ and $a$, such that $(f \circ g)'(a)$ exists, and $g'(a)$ exists, but $f'(g(a))$ does not.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, alexandroff-double-circle

Find an example of 2 functions $f$ and $g$ and a point $a \in 
\mathbb{R}$, such that $(f \circ g)'(a)$ and $g'(a)$ exists, but $f'(g(a))$ does not exist, and also $f$ and $g$ must take on all values in $\mathbb{R}$.

Same problem as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268392/the-composition-of-a-nowhere-differentiable-function-with-a-differentiable-funct).

The solution I came up with was

$a = 0 ~~~~~~~~ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x:  & x \geq0 \\
2x: & x \leq 0
\end{cases} \Bigr\} ~~~~~~~~ g(x) = x^3$

That's fine, but now I'm trying to find an example where $g'(a) \neq 0$, or alternatively prove $g'(a) \neq 0 \implies f'(g(a))$ exists.

I'm not even sure which conclusion is correct.

Comment: Keep in mind that if everything existed, then $(f\circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a))\cdot g'(a)$ so the only way the composite could exist but the individual component not is if you had something akin to $0\cdot \infty$ or $0$ times a non existent but bounded limit, or a bounded non limit canceling out another one.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi I don't understand, why couldn't it be something akin to, say, $1 \cdot \infty$?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi Because if $f'(g(a)) \cdot g'(a)$ doesn't exist, that doesn't necessarily imply $(f \circ g)'(a)$ doesn't exist, no?

Comment: My comment was for your second inquiry not the initial problem

Comment: @Ninad Munshi $1 \neq 0$?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi When you say "the composite", are you referring to $(f \circ g)'(a)$, or $f'(g(a)) \cdot g'(a)$?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume in addition that $g'$ is continuous then $g'(a)\ne0$, $f\circ g$ differentiable imply $f$ differentiable.

Because now $g$ is a local homeoomorphism; if $h$ is a local inverse for $g$ near $a$ then $f=(f\circ g)\circ h$ is differentiable, being the composition of two differentiable functions.

Comment: How do you get $f = (f \circ g) \circ (g')^{-1}$ near $a$?

Comment: Do you mean $h$ is a local inverse for $g$ near $a$?

Comment: @SenZen Yes, I meant inverse for $g$; thanks.

Comment: What if $g'$ is not continuous at $a$?